# UIPickerView recognice also "small" scroll changes

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

in UIPickerView there is this delegate UIPickerViewDelegate which catches changes in a component for the selected row. How can i recognice "smaller" changes? For example getting the current frame-values of a subview in a scroller-component (coordinates of the view) -updating very often. Is there a way to catch an animation key or something?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly subclass it and then look for touchBegan to be called, but the target action is only performed when the component comes to a stop at an actual slide. You may be using the simulator and seeing that the new value isn't registered right away, but in practice, someone using the picker would want to make sure the correct slide was picked before doing anything else.